# is 40 minutes enough layover time at Munich airport for a connecting international flight leading outside Schengen region?

Tags: short-connections, lufthansa, munich, airport-terminals, muc

I have a flight from Munich to Delhi in few days and I will arrive at Terminal 2 of Munich airport (MUC) with Lufthansa. The layover at the airport (MUC) is only 40 minutes. My departure flight is with Oman Air from Terminal 2 in just 40 minutes of my arrival.

I am an Indian citizen and have resident permit of one of EU nations.So,I will have to pass through the immigration department and security screening as well (my check-in would be done in previous airport).

*Interestingly, Munich airport terminal 2 was planned as such that passengers can have connecting flight in 30 minutes ([Reference](https://www.executivetraveller.com/just-30-minutes-connecting-time-at-munich-how-lufthansa-does-it)).*

I am not sure if it is trustworthy or in other words, not sure if it is wise enough to take the risk and trust the German efficiency.
Is there anyone with first hand similar experience? or do you know anything related?

Comment: Is this a single ticket?  Do you have checked bags? Even with a single ticket I've had issues through-checking bags onto Oman Airways (although that wasn't from Lufthanda, but another Star Alliance airline)

Comment: Can you clarify where you are arriving from (on the first flight). My understanding is that you arrive from another Schengen-area airport but that’s not completely clear.

Comment: As far as I can tell Oman doesn't fly from Munich to Delhi (at least not directly). Please add ALL relevant detail. What is your exact itinerary and how was it booked

Comment: Not sure that this a duplicate. My original answer is 8 years old and connection in Munich depends a lot on whether you need to ride the bus and/or transfer to/from the satellite  terminal. Without proper details it's hard to tell.

Comment: Forty minutes is tight, but possible. Make sure the crew on the flight to Munich knows that you have a tight connection. This happens all the time; there are ground staff who meet flights and help people with short connections. They may even help get you through passport control quickly. But despite this, there's still a very high chance that you'll miss your flight simply because your arrival in Munich could be delayed. But look, your flight is in a few days; what can you do about it now? Rescheduling will cost at least a few hundred euros. Let Lufthansa put you in a hotel overnight.

Comment: @Hilmar obviously the flight from Munich will be to Oman with a subsequent leg from there to Delhi.  That doesn't matter for the purpose of this question, however, does it?  We know the flight departs from a non-Schengen gate in terminal 2.  Why would more information help?